# Need to Sum Values in One Column of Excel if Values in Previous Column Match

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, sumifs

I am trying to create a new column by combining names in one column, only if the they belong to the same team name in a previous column. I've tried SumIf and VLookup functions, but I can't get it to pull.

For example, in Column G needs to read "Name 1", "Name 2", and so on. The names come from Column F. Only those names in Column F that have the same value in Column C should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be an example of your problem?

```
Teams   Names   A         B             C
A       Ben     Ben         
C       Brian                           Brian 
B       Adrian            Adrian    
C       Betty                           Betty 
B       Peter             Peter     
A       Tom     Tom         

                Ben Tom   Adrian Peter  Brian Betty
```

Comment: Very similar, yes. Except in a "D" column, I would need to list what currently pictured as the last row- all the individual names in the team.